# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed in VBA but doesn't when using 'select'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to speed up my macro which is copying and pasting formulas in a series of columns into the adjacent columns. Initially the code ran using

```
For i = 1 To j
        ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(NumofResultsLineNamesRange), Columns(NumofResultsLineNamesRange + 119)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next i
```

However I'm copying hundreds of columns and this is very slow to run. I am trying to get away from using 'Select' to speed up the macro and have recoded it like this:

```
Dim ResultTemplateSheet As Worksheet
    Set ResultTemplateSheet = Sheets("01")
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
j = Sheets("Input").Range("C16").Value - 2
Dim LineNameFormula As Range
Dim NumofSummaryLineNamesRange As Integer

    ResultTemplateSheet.Range("A4").Calculate
    NumofSummaryLineNamesRange = ResultTemplateSheet.Range("A4").Value
    Set LineNameFormula = ResultTemplateSheet.Range(Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange), Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 3))
    LineNameFormula.Copy Destination:=ResultTemplateSheet.Range(Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 4), Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 4 * (j + 1)))
```

Now i am getting the "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" error message for this line:

```
Set LineNameFormula = ResultTemplateSheet.Range(Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange), Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 3))
```

I have tried dropping the `Set` from the line, I have double checked that `NumofSummaryLinesRange` is an integer but I can't help feeling this is a syntax error yet I can't figure out where?

Most confusingly it seems to work fine if I revert to `Select`. However i would like to avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: Repeat the worksheet object qualifier for the `Columns` calls: `Set LineNameFormula = ResultTemplateSheet.Range(ResultTemplateSheet.Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange), ResultTemplateSheet.Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `With` statement and adding `.` before your `Columns` reference will fully qualify it with your `ResultTemplateSheet` worksheet type object.

```
With ResultTemplateSheet ' <-- Use With Statement
    .Range("A4").Calculate
    NumofSummaryLineNamesRange = .Range("A4").Value
    Set LineNameFormula = .Range(.Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange), .Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 3))
    LineNameFormula.Copy Destination:=.Range(.Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 4), .Columns(NumofSummaryLineNamesRange + 4 * (j + 1)))
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but I'm not sure how!? I thought by being explicit and using `worksheet.Range` it would be unambiguous. Is it the `.Columns` where it was not fully qualified and does the `.` refer to the `Range` or to the `Worksheet`?

Comment: @K_M the `Columns` was not fully qualified with the `Worksheet` object.  The `.` refers to the `Worksheet` object